# how to ensure 100% code coverage of git commits with grunt-mocha-cov

Tags: git, gruntjs, code-coverage, mocha.js, blanket.js

I am trying to set up a continuos integration environment (using quick build) wherein on every commit to a git branch I want to run our test suite, check code coverage and revert commits if either the test fails or the code coverage is below a certain threshold. In particular I want to ensure that the code I am checking in is 100% tested. Our test suite has been set up using grunt and mocha-hack and we are using grunt-mocha-cov for coverage. But grunt-mocha-cov instruments the whole source code. I want only the git diffs to be instrumented. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: (full disclosure, I built this) You can use https://codecov.io to upload reports and create Github Status updates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool named [diff-cover](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff-cover), which can check coverage for git diffs. It takes Cobertura XML coverage reports and compares with the output of `git diff`. It then reports coverage information for lines in the diff.

I cannot see whether *grunt-mocha-cov* is able to output Cobertura reports, but you should be able to find some grunt plugin that does.

Note that *diff-cover* doesn't help you to avoid unneccessary coverage instrumentation for performance reasons.